# How to update password that was given in GRANT?

Tags: mysql

Say I do this for a user:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myus'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'grantpass';

How can I update that password?

I know that doing this:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'myus'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
```

Will update the password that was created in the CREATE USER command, but how do I update the password for the GRANT command?

Comment: GRANT is not a separate entity. GRANT syntax requires password to authenticate changes. changing a password on the user afterwards does not flush the privileges. if you try the grant command with the old password it simply fails because it needs the latest password to work

Comment: Er... where are you seeing that the same password isn't used for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update mysql.user set Password = password('newpassword')
where mysql.User = 'yourUser' and mysql.Host = 'yourHost';

flush privileges;
```